# How to open a plain TeX document in BaKoMaTeX (TeXword)

Tags: plain-tex, bakoma

The question says it all

I want to open a plain Tex equation in BaKoMaTeX (TeXWord)

This is a Sample File

```
$$ t{\rm{(}}x{\rm{,}}y{\rm{)}} = \left\{ {\matrix{ 1 \cr 0 \cr } } \right.\matrix{ {\quad \quad \quad \quad {\rm{when}}\;\sqrt {(x^2 + y^2 )} \le r} \cr {{\rm{otherwise}}} \cr } $$
```

Comment: BaKoMaTeX is a LaTeX editor, not a general TeX one. I'm not sure you can edit plain TeX files in BaKoMa, given the fact it's aiming at something more than just being a text editor with dedicated TeX features.

Comment: @JosephWright, Actually my question is can we open a Plain tex File in Bakoma Tex and Edit Visually like we do for Latex Files??

Comment: I don't know about BakoMaTeX, but I'd like to comment on your equation; are you perhaps trying to get something like: `$$ t(x,y) = \cases{1 & when $\sqrt{(x^2 + y^2)} \le r$ \cr 0 & otherwise} $$`

Comment: @morbusg, whatever equation doesn't matters for me, i will be getting equations in Plain Tex Format, i want to open it in BakoMa Texword for Editing(WYSIWYG) purpose

Comment: @user52124 As I've already said, BaKoMa is explicitly a LaTeX-focussed system, and as it's more than just a text editor it's very hard to imagine it will work with plain. However, you'll find very few people here with experience with BaKoMa, and may well be best asking the technical support for what is a commercial application.

Comment: This isn't plain TeX code, this is obscure code. `$$ t{\rm{(}...`: an author of the code meant that `(` is not in `\rm` automatically. But it is. Moreover, `\rm{(}` is bad coding, because `\rm` isn't a macro with parameter, it is font switcher: all after `\rm` is roman. And two matrices for `\cases` construction is next obscure thing in this code. See morbusg's comment how to code such formula.

Answer (score 6):

BaKoMa TeX 11.0 published 1-Sep-2015 includes TeXWord which can open Plain TeX and AmsTeX documents.

Comment: Do not forget append \bye command at end of your sample code.

Comment: Don't forget to tell that TeXWord is commercial software: €77 with one year upgrades, which I can't consider a “small fee”.

Comment: It is just answer of a question. I am sure that asking user know even more details about prices. About small fee - I think 100 EUR is small fee. Every one have own opinion about ranges of small values.

Answer (score 2):

BaKoMaTeX is a LaTeX editor, not a general TeX one. I'm not sure you can edit plain TeX files in BaKoMa, given the fact it's aiming at something more than just being a text editor with dedicated TeX features. You will probably be best asking the technical support for what is a commercial application.